# Attach a label to rotating wheel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a wheel menu that rotates when touching it and you can select an item on the wheel and and rotate it again...

Its actually one image of circle, what i want to do is to attach  a label with text to each section, and they should rotate together.

I created an instance of it:

```
myWheel *wheel= [[myWheel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,45, 282, 282)];
```

and tried to stick label to it:

```
[addSubview:myUILabel];
```

its create label,but i cant cause it to spin together...

Comment: how have you tried to rotate them?

Comment: Whatever code you're using to rotate your wheel should work for your label too.

Comment: for the wheel i have functions that calculating angels and all that... the problem is how to attach it to that wheel

Comment: Why don't you just add the labels to your wheel's image?

Comment: the image is static, but the labels are dynamic, the will be changing from WS.

Comment: Show us the code that rotates and how you set the wheel to be able to rotate.

Comment: its a big project...How i rotate it is not the point here,it can be a box for example that moves with the finger and a label should move also

Answer (score 0):

You should have a UIView contain your image for your wheel as a subview to it, as well as the labels.  Then any spinning/rotating you do should be done on the UIView (which will maintain the position and angles of all labels you place).

**EDIT:**

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[container addSubview:wheelImage];
[container addSubview:labelOne];
[container addSubview:labelTwo];
```

Comment: can you write example of that? cant understand how they connected together in one View.

Comment: Something like my edit shows.  Then you would just do the rotation on "container"

Comment: well my function that rolls the wheel is getting only image, i cant sent it UIView, in the init i have only initwithImage or Frame but without a UIView...any idea how to continue?